# Can't get First Project to run - Spring Roo

Tags: spring-roo

I have searched all over for somebody else with this issue and found nothing...so hopefully I can get this solved here.

I got one of the sample apps to work, but it didnt use the web mvc, so it has to do with whatever that sets up.

I have downloaded Roo (spring-roo-1.2.0.RELEASE) and Maven (apache-maven-2.2.1) and set up paths per install instructions.

I can get Roo to run just fine, but after finishing the steps:

```
mkdir hello
cd hello
roo
roo> hint
roo> project --topLevelPackage com.foo
roo> jpa setup --provider HIBERNATE --database HYPERSONIC_IN_MEMORY
roo> entity jpa --class ~.Timer --testAutomatically
roo> field string --fieldName message --notNull
roo> hint web mvc
roo> web mvc setup
roo> web mvc all --package ~.web
roo> selenium test --controller ~.web.TimerController
roo> web gwt setup
roo> perform tests
roo> quit
```

When I try to run app using mvn jetty:run I get the following (I get same using tomcat):

```
[INFO] Starting jetty 8.0.1.v20110908 ...
[INFO] Started Jetty Server
2012-02-18 11:38:06,868 [qtp992502906-21] ERROR org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.ThemeTag - Theme 'purple': No message found under code 'styleSheet' for locale 'en_US'.
javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Theme 'purple': No message found under code 'styleSheet' for locale 'en_US'.
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.MessageTag.do StartTagInternal(MessageTag.java:184)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContex tAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:7 9)
at org.apache.jsp.tag.web.util.load_002dscripts_tagx. _jspx_meth_spring_theme_0(load_002dscripts_tagx.ja va from :134)
at org.apache.jsp.tag.web.util.load_002dscripts_tagx. doTag(load_002dscripts_tagx.java from :74)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.layouts.default_jspx._j spx_meth_util_load$1scripts_0(default_jspx.java from :114)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.layouts.default_jspx._j spService(default_jspx.java from :67)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(Http JspBase.java:109)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet .java:847)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.servic e(JspServletWrapper.java:408)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFil e(JspServlet.java:483)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspSe rvlet.java:373)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet .java:847)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(Ser vletHolder.java:558)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle( ServletHandler.java:489)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.han dle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle( SecurityHandler.java:520)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.do Handle(SessionHandler.java:233)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.do Handle(ContextHandler.java:972)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(S ervletHandler.java:417)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.do Scope(SessionHandler.java:192)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.do Scope(ContextHandler.java:906)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.han dle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispat cher.java:267)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispat cher.java:98)
at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesReque stContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java: 241)
at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesReque stContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java :222)
at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRe nderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttribu teRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.ja va:106)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(B asicTilesContainer.java:670)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(B asicTilesContainer.java:690)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(B asicTilesContainer.java:644)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(B asicTilesContainer.java:627)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(B asicTilesContainer.java:321)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesV iew.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:124)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView. render(AbstractView.java:262)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet. render(DispatcherServlet.java:1157)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet. doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:927)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet. doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.p rocessRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.d oGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet .java:734)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet .java:847)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(Ser vletHolder.java:558)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedCha in.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1362)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityMana gerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManager InViewFilter.java:147)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilte r.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedCha in.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1333)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFil ter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:7 7)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilte r.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedCha in.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1333)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFi lter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java :88)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilte r.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedCha in.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1333)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle( ServletHandler.java:487)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.han dle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle( SecurityHandler.java:520)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.do Handle(SessionHandler.java:233)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.do Handle(ContextHandler.java:972)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(S ervletHandler.java:417)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.do Scope(SessionHandler.java:192)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.do Scope(ContextHandler.java:906)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.han dle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCol lection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:250)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection .handle(HandlerCollection.java:149)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.ha ndle(HandlerWrapper.java:110)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java :350)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequ est(HttpConnection.java:442)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHan dler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:910)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpPa rser.java:565)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(H ttpParser.java:217)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handl e(AsyncHttpConnection.java:46)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.han dle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:545)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.r un(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:43)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.run Job(QueuedThreadPool.java:598)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.r un(QueuedThreadPool.java:533)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2012-02-18 11:38:06,902 [qtp992502906-21] ERROR org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.ThemeTag - Theme 'purple': No message found under code 'styleSheet' for locale 'en_US'.
javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Theme 'purple': No message found under code 'styleSheet' for locale 'en_US'....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you have tried to use both GWT and Spring MVC Controllers for your web application.

Use only one, and it would work.

Cheers and all the best with Roo. :)

Comment: Thanks!  That was it...curious as to why that tutorial that I followed is the on the Spring Roo website.

Comment: You're welcome :) Maybe the tutorial was introducing both and branched later on. The initial steps are common for all. All the best with Roo!